# Вычислить последовательность факториалов без циклов и ветвления

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, функциональное-программирование

> Для заданной последовательности чисел [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  выведите последовательность факториалов: 0!,1!,2!,…,n! Задачу необходимо решить в функциональном стиле.

Моя проблема заключается в том, что в программе присутствует if, а его использовать нельзя. Также нельзя пользоваться циклами. Подскажите как избавиться от if-ов. Вот мой код. Заранее благодарю.

```
from itertools import accumulate
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a = map(lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x, a) # [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(*accumulate(a, lambda x, y: x * y))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если просто `a[0] = 1` совсем не годится, то так:

```
from itertools import accumulate
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a = map(lambda x: max(x,1), a)
print(*accumulate(a, lambda x, y: x * y))
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

`lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x, a` это и любой `if` можно конвертировать в

```
def func(x):
    try:
         assert x == 0
         return 1
    except AsertationError:
         return x
```

Comment: Жалко, стиль не функциональный =)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from math import factorial

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(*map(factorial, numbers))
```

Вывод:

```
1 1 2 6 24 120 720
```

При желании, можно [`math.factorial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial) самостоятельно определить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import operator
from functools import reduce    

def factorial(n):
    return reduce(operator.mul, range(1, n + 1), 1)

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(*map(factorial, numbers))
```

Вывод тот же.

Оба способа работают для произвольной последовательности натуральных чисел -- в любом порядке. Если у вас на входе числа всегда подряд идут, тогда действительно [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) подходит:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools
import operator

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(*itertools.accumulate([1] + numbers[1:], operator.mul))
# -> 1 1 2 6 24 120 720
```

Для неограниченного ввода, можно на `itertools.chain` и `itertools.islice` перейти.